# Unable to see hive table data(stored as Parquet file format) in CLI

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet

I have saved hive table as Parquet format and loaded local data into it successfully. When performing a `select` operation on the table I get this error:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://localhost.localdomain:9000/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db/studentam/studarray is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [48, 48, 54, 10]
Time taken: 0.434 seconds


create table studentAM(id int,name string,subject array<string>,mark map<string,int>,year int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' collection items terminated by '#' map keys terminated by '$' lines terminated by '\n' stored as parquet;

file content:

1,subhash,math#eng#science,math$67#eng$60#science$85,2006
2,kundan,geo#social#pol,geo$79#social$70#pol$81,2007
3,sakesh,eng#math,eng$89#math$75,2006

load data local inpath 'studarray' into table studentam;
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Create text_table with similar columns

Step 2 : Load data into text_table

Step 3 : Insert data into parquet_table from text_table.

```
  insert into Parquet_table as select * from text_table;
```